# Multiply by regrouping in dax?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset grouped by two rows as below

```
GroupName    Score   Multiply
Group1        2      
Group2        3
Group2        5
Group1        1
```

I have a slicer based on the parameter table for storing the above GroupName values. so when I select Group1( I am using a selected function on variable in my dax) I want to multiply all rows for Group1(scores) by 4 and all rows for Group2(score) by 6.

I tried this but it is updating all rows.

```
var a=4*score
var b=6*score
var mm=selectedvalue('Group Paramter'[Group Name])

Return if( mm ="Group1", a, b)
```

But it multiplies all rows, how can I multiply by grouping using GroupName?

How can I achieve this? I apperciate for any help.

Comment: You are using a Measure or Custom column?

Answer (score 0):

You can try some logic as below (**measure**)-

```
var mm = selectedvalue('Group Paramter'[Group Name])

Return if( mm ="Group1", min(table_name[score]) * 4, min(table_name[score]) * 6)
```